# Is there a way I can apply to a plane the pattern of a corrugated sheet?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, edit-mode, archipack-add-on

In this case, I'm doing a corrugated sheet, but it could be anything else.
I found this add-on called Jarch vis, which works the way I wish I could do this. For example, you can use it to make a terracotta roof out of planes and config other parameters.
What it's good about this is that makes the workflow really faster, because every terracotta tile will always be equal and this add-on will cut out what doesn't fit on the plane. And the same I want to happen with a corrugated sheet, the curvature will be the same, adaptable, besides being in whatever plane, position, rotation, or form (if it's a triangle, it´ll be adapted to this). [image]

[image]

Comment: You can make the brick texture with 3 arrays, then delete faces only. And use knife project to project the edges onto another plane.

Comment: With bricks you can, but with corrugated sheets it's important also to have information at least in 2 axis because that won't project the curves and you'll have to do them manually. I want to do the curves once, as a pattern, and then apply that pattern to the planes.

Comment: Do you want it to be actual cut out geometry? Or just the texture?